# how to make box with theorem style

Tags: thmtools

[image: how to make theorem box using by declaretheoremstyle same below.]

how to make theorem box using by declaretheoremstyle same below.

Comment: Does the solution *have to* be based on the `thmtools` package, or will solution approaches be acceptable?

Comment: For boxes like this I would always use [package `tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). However, it currently does not provide a theorem library based on `thmtools`. But because the shown box is just a frame with title and with text and math inside, but not number etc. a `tcbox` should be usable.

Comment: Please EDIT your question and add code, which we can copy&compile AND shows your 3 lines of theorem.